# how to prevent my app from sending data through proxy?

Tags: sockets, amazon-web-services, networking, tcp, proxy

I am developing a chat back-end application on `aws` cloud. In order to make a scalable architecture for the chat back-end I must ensure that the one who is opening a connection is the real one.

To be more accurate that chat ofcourse must keep a `tcp` connection open with the server all the time and I have the following problems:

1 - the back-end has a load balancer `elastic load balancer`.

2 - the `tcp` connection between the client app and the back-end server must stay open and alive. which mean the app must keep the connection alive with the server not the `elb` load balancer.

3 - the `elb` load balancer must send the connection and load through a session table `sticky session` to the same server the app connected to before.
unfortunately, the load balancer only support `l4` and `l7` layers and I think I need to use the `l3` layer.

the main problem here is most people operate behind proxy server so I can't maintain a connection with them because the `tcp` connection will be made with the proxy and not their app.

I don't know how to solve this but the only solution that I know now is:
I must prevent the users from operating behind any proxy servers to make sure the tcp connection is direct with them not the proxy, how do I do that?

If there is a way to let them operate behind a proxy and a solution can be made on the back-end tell me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your concern. If you are using web sockets, most proxies would allow this type of communication but they can cause you troubles as well if they have timeouts and such.

You cannot control whether someone is behind a proxy. In many cases the proxy will be completely transparent so you'd have no way to know it is there without inspecting all of the network hops. You may want to read up further on this. A good start is this article -

https://www.infoq.com/articles/Web-Sockets-Proxy-Servers

If you are attempting to use the IP address as an authentication mechanism, I suggest instead using a standard authentication mechanism. Once authenticated, you should manage the session using either session cookies, JWT, or another standard session management solution. Note that JWT is typically stateless (doesn't use a session) but can be used to authorize a user to session type data.

Comment: ok then how i can make a chat app that must open tcp connection ith servers ?

Comment: the proxy server will then make the connection and not the real app

Comment: The app will make the connection still. It is just done so by routing through the proxy server.

Comment: yes but when the server accepts listening to the sockets tcp made by the app it will see the ip adress of the proxy right ? if right is that a problem or no ?

Comment: That should be no issue if using proper authentication to identify the user.

Comment: you mean the proxy might change ip so i dont depend on it and add the authentication mechanism i want in the data secction to know who is connecting like a cookie or secret key right ?

Comment: Yes, I would expect for proper security you'd want to have a user authenticate and then validate the session on each subsequent request. This could use a cookie, JWT, or other standard mechanism. Relying on an IP address is not secure since it is possible to spoof IP addresses and IPs can change.

Comment: ok and i make the ELB load balancer load with tcp layer ( load tcp connections across servers ) and i will use the authentication to know who is connecting .. right ? Thanks alot man you saved my time :D

Comment: Correct. Please mark the answer as answered if you have a pat forward now.